# Ternary Operator in Gridview

Tags: vb.net, gridview, conditional-operator, ternary

I am looking to make this statement work in a VB.net page:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="TableHeader" >
<ItemStyle Width="30px" />
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbxClientsActive" 
 Text='<%# Eval("Inactive").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Not Active " : " Active " %>'
 checked='<%#Eval("Inactive")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The ternary operator is causing a error: Compiler Error Message: BC36637: The '?' character cannot be used here.

I want to use a tenary operator to display text based on the the field Inactive containing a true or false text value.

Comment: The eval() function is not javascript? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: Since the embedded script code in an Asp.net page can be in multiple languages (typically c# or vb.net, but could be others) it's hard to help you when you are not providing info on which language you're using. There should be a language="c#" or similar at the top of the page.

Comment: It is a Vb.net page. I know I can get around the error by making a javascript function, my question is how to make the Tenary operator work in this statement. If I can find a way it will help in many other areas simular to this. Still I do not understand what that has to do this particular issue in a gridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is server side script code and must be written in VB.NET if the page is in that language. There is no `?` operator, use the `If` operator instead.

Comment: That makes sense, the ? is what I use in C and am most familuar with. I did not think to make that connection. Oh the joy of learning VB.net programming.

Comment: –1 … `IIf` is deprecated. Use the ternary `If` operator instead, it corresponds exactly to C#’s conditional operator.

Comment: Good point @Konrad, just figured out that IIF doesn't support short circuit :/

Comment: @Konrad, Thank you for pointing that out. It is working as intended now.